# Div display after 9 sec in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a div with the following css:

```
height: 100%;
background: rgba(41, 39, 38, 0.8);
opacity: 0.85;
position: absolute;
z-index: 99999;
width: 100%;
top: 0;
display: none
```

I want to know how to display the div 9 seconds after the DOM is ready. How is this possible with jquery?

Comment: @AlienArrays That's not a typo! at last you can avoid using semicolon but it's best practice to keep that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very easy to do this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.myDivsClass').delay(9000).fadeIn();
});
```

The 9000 is 9000 milliseconds, which is equal to 9 seconds.

The `fadeIn()` by default takes 400 milliseconds to fade in. So if you want it to show the div right away after the 9 seconds, with no fading in animation, just put a `0` (zero) in the fade in, like this `fadeIn(0)`